# Импорт MySQL таблицы в таблицу сайта

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую всех

Есть файл `*.sql` (таблица, импорт из MySQL) , есть бд на сайте, в которой есть определенная таблица (пустая), в которую нужно импортировать файл `*.sql`. Решение простое, зайти в панель управления сайтом, а phppmyadmin, и за 20 секунд импортировать нужную таблицу.

Можно ли сделать это же действия по средствам php/mysql команд, и как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать системную команду(system). Не знаю возможно ли это в windows(всмысле не знаю есть ли там команда **mysql**) но в *nix это можно сделать примерно так:

```
system('mysql -u <user> -p<password> dbname < filename.sql');
```

Comment: ответ хорош, но я на хостинг собираюсь импортировать данные. интересовало написание PHP файлы который забрасывается на хостинг и запускается

Comment: @frank, ну так это и есть кусочек php файла который будет делать то, что Вам нужно. Только вот не известно разрешена ли будет команда system на хостинге...

Comment: видимо на моем хостинге такая команда не поддерживается. саму команду прописал так (myuser, mypass - пользователь и пароль бд, mybase - бд, filename.sql - файлик для импорта)

    system('mysql -u myuser -p mypass mybase < filename.sql');

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно распарсить *.sql в теле php и выполнить запросы последовательно, я пользуюсь таким кодом:

```
    $dump=file_get_contents('path/to/file.sql');
    $q=''; $state=0; $coco=0;
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($dump);$i++){
        switch($dump{$i}){
            case '"': if($state==0) $state=1; elseif($state==1) $state=0; break;
            case "'": if($state==0) $state=2; elseif($state==2) $state=0; break;
            case "`": if($state==0) $state=3; elseif($state==3) $state=0; break;
            case ";":
                if($state==0) {
                    //echo $q."\n;\n";
                    mysql_query($q);
                    $q='';
                    $state=4;
                    $coco++;
                }
                break;
            case "\\": if(in_array($state,array(1,2,3))) $q.=$dump[$i++]; break;
        }
        if($state==4) $state=0; else $q.=$dump{$i};
    }
    echo'Выполнено запросов: '.$coco;
```

естественно, уже после соединения с БД и выбора базы (это вы явно умеете).
Взят уже не помню где, но работает исправно.

Comment: Уважаемый, конструкцию немного поясните? в какое место прописывать запрос INSERT ? вот в место этого: mysql_query($q); ?

Comment: предполагается, что весь код, т.е. CREATE-ы, INSERT-ы, и т.д. уже есть в файле *.sql (он легко читаем из блокнота)
здесь группа переключателей, которые парсят горстку символов и вытягивают из них собственно SQL-запросы, выполняя по меренахождения.

Comment: классно конечно, в моем случае 'Выполнено запросов: 11' , но изменений я так и не увидел в бд

Comment: я этот код использую для построения базовой структуры БД и её минимального наполнения в установщике самописного движка. Всё работает исправно. Дебаг Вам в руки. он открытый, выводить его продукты жизнедеятельности никто не мешает.

Comment: За код еще раз благодарю, не сработало т.к. сам перемудрил

Comment: Успешных изысканий, в новом году!

Answer (score 0):

Командная строка #

mysql -p

вбиваем пароль root

use db;

source db.sql;

ГДЕ:

db - база данных для импорта из файла db.sql

Если видим это:

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

то профит.