# Проверка выполнения команды system на сервере. Действие импорта таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую всех еще раз

Есть команда по импорту таблицы в бд-mysql сайта [данная мне в прошлой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/175106/php-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-mysql-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0) . Тут 3 варианта есть:

1. все сработает - и реально данные окажутся в бд/таблице сайта
2. ничего не сработает - т.к. данная команда запрещена на хостинге
3. ничего не сработает - если команду прописать неверно (что частенько бывает в моем случае)

(да я понимаю тех поддержка рулит, но если хостингов много - хочется обойтись без телефонных звонков)

Можно ли проверить поддержку данной команды на хостинге каким либо PHP скриптом. Поддерживается она или нет, и если поддерживается то ест ли ошибки при выполнении или нет?

```
// теория, импорт таблицы в бд сайта
system('mysql -u <user> -p<password> dbname < filename.sql');

// практика (myuser, mypass, mybase, filename.sql - пользователь и пароль пальзователя бд, сама бд, имя файла бд)
system('mysql -u myuser -p mypass mybase < filename.sql');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `system()` возвращает `false` при неудаче. То есть если она запрещена то она должна вернуть `false`.

Если функция срабатывает то она возвращает вывод команды. Этот вывод можно проверить например на ключевые слова типа "`error`". Это можно сделать простым регулярным выражением.
Желательно конечно изучить вывод команды `mysql` и посмотреть, что эта команда выводит при успешном и завершении и при завершении с ошибкой. Ну и на основе этого уже составлять регулярное выражение.

Мне кажется, это какое-то костыльное решение. Может быть знающие люди меня дополнят или исправят.

Comment: про вывод ошибки понял. а по поводу решение, оно есть, даже указал подобное для mysqli, только вот для mysql оно запрятано на просторах интернета

Comment: @frank, а почему бы не перейти на mysqli. Он посовременней будет. А mysql уже официально устаревший. http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799
Или не имеется такой возможности пока?

Answer (score 2):

А что мешает заливать данные через скрипт непосредственно неиспользую системные комманды?

вот скрипт загрузки дампа в базу с использованием функций mysql) при желании можешь на PDO передалать

```
<?php
// тут ваша конфа подключения к бд

//файл с дампом
$filename="file.sql";

$fp=fopen($filename,"r");
$contents=fread($fp,filesize($filename));
fclose($filename);

$querys=preg_split("#;[\s]*\r\n)#is",$contents);

foreach ($querys as $query)
{
    if(!mysql_query($query)) exit(mysql_error());

}
```

работает с правильно составленым дампом для MYSQL

Comment: поделитесь командами. тогда мешать ничего не будет. просто импортировать всю таблицу filename.sql лежащую на хостинге в нужную бд/таблицу сайта (она изначально пуста)

великим интернетом нашел только решение для mysqli

    http://www.php.su/forum/topic.php?forum=68&topic=732